# What do the Valgrind errors mean for my program

Tags: c

I'm having a hard time implementing a function that frees the memory for my hash table

```
void free_table(node *table[MAX_HASH], int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    free_table(table, num -1);
    free_list(table[num-1]);
}

void free_list(node *listp)
{
    if (listp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    free_list(listp->next);
    free(listp);
}
```

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
>
> HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 1,342 bytes allocated
>
> All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>
> For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

It says that there are no memory leaks and the program runs properly when I use it, what causes the errors and what can they do to my program?

The whole code: https://pastebin.com/9cVQsNzW

Comment: Is there more than that from valgrind? Such as a stack trace? It is telling you that some parts of the code are accessing unintialised variables. Such accesses result in "undefined behaviour". UB means it may appear to "work" but can have more negative results (e.g. crash) at any time. That's why tools like valgrind are important as they help you catch these errors before they blow up at some point.

Comment: `rerun with: -v` Did you rerun with `-v`?

Comment: From a quick look it appears your `get_input` function does not set `temp->next`.

Comment: Make sure you build your code with debug information (the `-g` flag for `gcc`). Then Valgrind can print the location of the problems it finds in your code.